# Magmi imported products don't show all attributes defined in attribute sets

Tags: magento-1.7, magento, magmi

I have to import about 2000 products in Magento and since the native import tool is very slow we decided to use magmi.

What we have done is create about 20 custom attributes, created a new attribute set (based on the default set) and add all these attributes to the new custom set.
(Magento is set up as multistore for a .de/.at domain)

With magmi I made a test import with one single test article, the import runs fine (no errors). But in the backend there are a few fields missing (like "price"); Not the values are missing but the fields are simply not shown.

Here is an example of the csv I use:

```
"attribute_set";"type";"sku";"websites";"name";"description";"short_description";"z_bottled";"status";"tax_class_id";"category_ids";"price";"special_price"
"z_article";"Simple Product";"123456";"base";"MAGMI Produkt";"Description";"Kurzbeschreibung";"2012";"1";"2";"87,88,105";"123";"123"
```

Comment: Servus! :) I don't know Magmi, but do you want continuous importing functionality (like syncing Magento with some other product database) or is this a one time thing? If you only need it once, I would recommend not wasting time with some plugin but write the one-off import code yourself.. it's really not that hard.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- you lack "store" column, put "admin" in it or use value replacer plugin to force it to "admin" value.
  however,this may also work without since magmi is "normally" able to default it to this value.

also ,maybe you need to launch flat reindexing & price reindexing.

Comment: Hi dweeves! Thanks for your tool! I just solved the problem: Instead of "Simple Product" I had to write "simple" --> Then all fields are here! YAY!